# drop-down list another query

Tags: custom-taxonomy

i tried this code, it is not giving me any 404 page instead it is giving me the same page back, now i think the submit buttons needs to be configured

```
function the_taxonomy_dropdown($taxonomy) {
  $id = "{$taxonomy}-dropdown";
  $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
  echo "<select name=\"{$id}\" id=\"{$id}\">";
  foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo '<option value="';
    echo get_term_link(intval($term->term_id),$taxonomy);
    echo '">' . "{$term->name}</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
}
add_action('init','jquery_init');
function jquery_init() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

this code was provided to me by one of the person from this website, i just modified it,
this works but its just showing me the home page again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a standard HTML form will do!

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" method="get">

    <p><?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=taxonomy-1&name=taxonomy-1'); ?></p>
    <p><?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=taxonomy-2&name=taxonomy-2'); ?></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Search!" /></p>

</form>
```

Just replace `taxonomy-1` and `taxonomy-2` with the names of *your* taxonomies.

### Important

If you registered your taxonomy with a custom `query_var`, you'll need to match it in the `name` argument of `wp_dropdown_categories()`.

Also, **querying multiple taxonomies is not supported as of 3.02** - you'll need the 3.1 beta, a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) or [additional filters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5055/query-posts-by-custom-post-type-and-custom-taxonomy/5057#5057).

Comment: i tried this but it is giving me 404 error for every search

Comment: Did you install the plugin or additional filters as indicated? As has been said, multiple taxonomy queries are not supported "as is"..

Comment: i am using GDCPT plugin for custom taxonomies,
just that i am using for for custom taxonomies

Comment: Could you post a link to the plugin?

Comment: yes
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-taxonomies-tools/

Comment: I've only just had a quick glance, but it doesn't seem to mention support for querying multiple taxonomies - you'll need another plugin or additional filters - check my original answer

Comment: see i tried this code @above chk my answer